# How to Replace any of these "/ \\ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *" Characters in a string with empty string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I would like to replace any of the below occurrence of characters in a string with empty string in asp.net c#
"/ \ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *"

i am trying to replace it with

```
mystring.contains('[')
 {
 mystring.Replace('[',' ');
 }
```

Currently i am doing it as above .
Is there a cleaner way of doing this.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: Use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: What is your full code? The cleaner solution is to create a `char[]` that contains all the different characters you wish to replace. Note: The `Contains` is not required since Replace will just not replace anything if it doesn't exist

Comment: I tired the below code but it always says no match
below are the sample strings i would be getting 

string groupName = abcnd&dfsdfdsf
string groupName = abcnd,dfsdfdsf
                                
if (Regex.IsMatch(groupName, @"[/ \\ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *]"))
{
    groupName = Regex.Replace(groupName, @"[/ \\ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *]", string.Empty);
}

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurences with an empty string as mentioned above or do you want to replace it with a space as shown in the code? That's a great difference.

Comment: @user3476088 there are lot of special characters in the ones you want to delete. Check the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx it won't be that easy straightforward to use Regex in such a case.

Comment: Hi Tim 
I want to replace any occurrence of the above chars with empty string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways:

1) via regex:

```
var pattern = @"[\/\\[\]\:\|\<>\+\=\;\,\?\*]";
var sample = "test * beacuse [a]";
var result = Regex.Replace(sample, 
                           pattern, 
                           string.Empty, 
                           RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

2) via linq:

```
var pattern = @"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*";
var result = new string(sample.Where(ch => !pattern.Contains(ch)).ToArray());
```

3) via StringBuilder:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char t in sample)
{
    if (!pattern2.Contains(t))
    {
        sb.Append(t);
    }
}

result = sb.ToString();
```

These ways are only samples ;)

Comment: I think you're unnecessarily escaping most of the other characters. Only `\ ` and `]` (unless you put it at the start) should need to be escaped. (On another note, how are you supposed to MarkDown a single backslash in code ticks?)

Comment: @Rawling Hmm, I've cheked with regex tester, without escaping regex was not valid. Maybe the checked was wrong.

Comment: I can believe a generic tester would make you escape `/` since it's usually the regex delimiter, but that's not necessary in C#. Most of the others (`[:|<>+=;,?*`) have no special meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple loop and you don't need to check first if it contains it at all:

```
foreach(char c in @"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*")
    mystring = mystring.Replace(c, ' ');
```

This replaces all occurences with a space similar to  your code. If you instead want to replace it with an empty string (as mentioned) you can use this:

```
foreach(char c in @"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*")
    mystring  = mystring.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
```

You could improve it a little bit by doing the replaces with a `System.Text.StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mystring);
foreach (char c in @"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*")
    sb.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
mystring = sb.ToString();
```

The `StringBuilder` is not necessarily more performant in terms of CPU cycles but in terms of memory consumption since it doesn't  create always new instances.

Comment: isn't it `mystring = mystring.Replace(c, ' ');` in `foreach` creating many unneccessary `string` instances?

Comment: @pwas: Don't underestimate the garbage collector. Also, there are just 14 replaces which is not so many. However, i've edited my answer to show a `StringBuilder`-approach.

Comment: Only 14 but.. What if source string is enormous? I know the GB will grab unused strings, but we don't know when. What's more, what's the purpose to add GB more work when there are ways to create in efficiently?

Comment: @pwas: as mentioned i've edited it to show an approach which costs less (temp) memory. _"but we don't know when"_ When objects are not referenced anymore (which is the case here) and the memory is needed.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it doesn't mean that we are allowed to waste memory when it's not needed - what's more when it doesn't make operation faster - creating many instances of big string will consume time also. Anyway, +1 for string builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression as mention by @ThreeFx. Another trick is to split the string and re-join it afterwards:

```
var toBeRemoved = new char[] { '[', ']', '/', '\\', ':', '|', '<', '>', '+', '=', ';', ',', '?', '*' };
mystring = string.Join(string.Empty, mystring.Split(toBeRemoved));
```

Comment: I have used regular expressions as below but it always says no match found .Am i doing anything wrong in below code string groupName = abcnd&dfsdfdsf string groupName = abcnd,dfsdfdsf if (Regex.IsMatch(groupName, @"[/ \\ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *]")) { groupName = Regex.Replace(groupName, @"[/ \\ [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? *]", string.Empty); }

Comment: @user3476088 your regex is invalid. You didn't escape special charscters.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple extension method if you find yourself needing to remove chars from strings like this fairly often:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Remove(this string self, params char[] charsToRemove)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in self)
            if (Array.IndexOf(charsToRemove, c) == -1)
                result.Append(c);

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

This should be fairly efficient.

By using a `params` argument, we have a couple of ways to call it, as demonstrated by this sample code:

```
string test = @"a/b\c[d]e:f|g<h>i+j=k;l,m?n*o";

// Pass an array of chars to remove:
string result1 = test.Remove(@"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(result1);

// Pass individually listed chars to remove:
string result2 = test.Remove('/', '\\', '[', ']', ':', '|', '<', '>', '+', '=', ';', ',', '?', '*');
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```