# Using LINQ lambda to replace characters from array in string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, replace

I have string array that contain characters that aren't allowed:

```
public static string[] IllegalCharacters = { "\"", "/", "\\", "[", "]", ":", "|", "<", ">", "+", "=", ";", ",", "?", "*", "\'", "@", ".", ":", "^", "¨", "å", "ä", "ö", "Å", "Ä", "Ö" };
```

I could remove the characters one after another with a foreach like this:

```
private string RemoveIllegalCharactersFromString(string text)
{
    foreach (string illegalCharacter in IllegalCharacters.IllegalCharacters)
    {
        text = text.Replace(illegalCharacter, "");
    }
    return text;
}
```

My question is could I remove the method by using a linq lambda expression instead?

What I'm using now:

```
public static HashSet<char> IllegalCharacters = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { '\"', '/', '\\', '[', ']', ':', '|', '<', '>', '+', '=', ';', ',', '?', '*', '\'', '@', '.', ':', '^', '¨','\'' });

var t = sourceText.Where(c => !IllegalCharacters.Contains(c)).ToArray();
var result = new string(t);
return result;
```

Comment: You should test if your approach isn't more efficient, you could improve it easily by using `StringBuilder.Replace` in a loop like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25154888/284240).

Comment: Could you provide any info why using a StringBuilder would be "faster"

Comment: i haven't said "faster" but "more efficient". It might use less memory or prevent the garbage collector from kicking in. So `StringBuilder.Replace` [can be more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6524918/284240).Btw, if you want to remove substrings instead of chars the LINQ approaches won't work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest changing `IllegalCharacters` into `char` collection (illegal characters should be *characters*, right?), e.g.

```
  public static HashSet<char> IllegalCharacters = new HashSet<char>(
    new char[] { '"', '\\', ..., 'Ä', 'Ö' });
```

And so you can put an evident Linq:

```
  string source = "123:+-456";

  string result = String.Concat(source
   .Where(c => !IllegalCharacters.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: I like `HashSet`(+1), which provides O(1) access.

Comment: That depends if "Å Ä Ö" are considered as characters. I will have to test this! Thanks!

Comment: Had problems with Concat so I replaced it with: var t = source.Where(c => !IllegalCharacters.Contains(c)).ToArray();
            var result = new string(t);
            return result;

Answer (score 3):

Here is a approach with Linq

```
string Text = "1:2+3[4]5|6";
string Result = new string(Text.Where(x => !IllegalCharacters.Contains(x.ToString())).ToArray());
```

I would store the characters in type `char` instead of `string` and use a `HashSet` instead of `string[]`:

```
HashSet<char> IllegalCharacters = new HashSet<char>() { '\'', '/', '\\', '[', ']', ':', '|', '<', '>', '+', '=', ';', ',', '?', '*', '\'', '@', '.', ':', '^', '¨', 'å', 'ä', 'ö', 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö' };

string Text = "1:2+3[4]5|6";
string Result = new string(Text.Where(x => !IllegalCharacters.Contains(x)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx). Like this:

```
private string RemoveIllegalCharactersFromString(string text)
{
    return IllegalCharacters.Aggregate(text, (current, illegalCharacter) => current.Replace(illegalCharacter, ""));
}
```

The result:

```
string result = RemoveIllegalCharactersFromString("HelloÄ[2536]:Y?eÖs*");
//Result => Hello2536Yes
```